# Hashing Algorithm for passwords

Tags: .net, security, encryption, password-encryption

I am looking for hashing algorithm to be used in my current application for password encryption. I came across this link

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Argon2[*7] is the winner of the password hashing competition and should be considered as your first choice for new applications;
PBKDF2 [*4] when FIPS certification or enterprise support on many platforms is required;
scrypt [*5] where resisting any/all hardware accelerated attacks is necessary but support isn’t.
bcrypt where PBKDF2 or scrypt support is not available.

I have not used any of these earlier projects, i know of SHa-256. But i would like to know which one is the best algorithm to encrypt passwords.
considering compute, memory used, return hash value length, whether we need to use salt value or not.

They also suggest Argon2 , but it is relatively new. can we use it? is it recommended?

Any suggestions on these.

Comment: Isn't SHA-256 good enough?

Comment: **No SHA-256 is not good enough**, it is fast which means that brute force attacks are viable. What is needed is a password hashing method that consumes substantial CPU time and resources, typically around 100ms, SHA-256 runs in about 1us for typical passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.

Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash.

Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions.

The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

PBKDF2 also known as Rfc2898 and Rfc2898DeriveBytes is the current NIST approved method, `Argon2` is an even better solution but is not as widely available.

Comment: Thank you zaph.I see argon2 code in git.. so can I use it or if you know of any other implementation of PBKDF2 in c#.net pls let me know

Comment: .NET calls PBKDF2 Rfc2898 or Rfc2898DeriveBytes, People like to make things difficult with naming.

Comment: You may also save some headache by checking NuGet for any of the suggested algorithms. There are dedicated packages for Bcrypt, Scrypt, and PBKDF2 you can install from there.